# Project fails to build in Eclipse under Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

So, I finally figured out how to update Java in Mac and managed to get my class with a SwingWorker work; previously, Java was complaining because I had Java 1.5 and 1.5 does not have SwingWorker. I wasn't able to change the default JRE in Mac though; I just linked the JRE 6 library in Eclipse so I can build. It is now happy even in the presence of SwingWorker.

However, when I try to build my project, I get the following error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'ProjectName'.
Exception occurred executing command line.
/Users/lab/Documents/workspace/ProjectName/.project: cannot execute
Exception occurred executing command line.
/Users/lab/Documents/workspace/ProjectName/.project: cannot execute
```

Anyone knows this error? I've tried cleaning the project then building again but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share your .project file to see what builders are involved.

Comment: Is that complete stack trace. Paste your code I will try it on mine.

Comment: Fro reference, there's a SwingWorker back-port [here](http://swingworker.dev.java.net).

Comment: do you get the same error even when you create a new project?

Comment: @Shahzeb, it's not even a stack trace. There's a window in Eclipse that pops up saying build encountered a problem. There's a "More details" button there, and clicking that shows the above message.

Comment: @Saket, There is actually a one-line stack trace, a NoClassDefFoundError . If what I read right, that means I didn't get to any .project file right? (Else, my question will be "Ummm...where do I find my .project file?")

Comment: The `.project` file would be right at the root folder of your Eclipse project (on the file system).

Comment: So, if my workspace is at Documents/workspace, I'll find the .project file right at Documents/workspace/ProjectName right? Err...there isn't any. Even tried looking at it via `ls` at the terminal. None. :|

Comment: dot file are hidden . Run this on the terminal and you should be able to see hidden files cut from here  defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you did not manage to set the default JRE version in Eclipse - this might be a problem, as simply adding the Java 6 libs might not work (e.g. classes compiled with Java 6 can be incompatible with Java 5 because of different byte code version).

First of all, open Preferences, and go to the Java/Installed JRE's page, and make sure that the newly installed Java 6 is available here. If not, add it as a Mac OSX VM. This has to be done manually, as Eclipse does not look for additional VMs after the first launch.

After the JRE is installed, update your project settings: right click on your project, select Properties, and in the Java build path page make sure that Java 6 is set as the JVM on the build tab - if not, then edit the entry, and select a Java VM 6 execution environment.

Finally (this step might not be needed), open the Run configuration, (Run/Run configurations... in menu), select your projects configuration, and on the main page make sure, that for runtime also a Java SE 6 VM or execution environment is selected.